# Using EasyDNS on a dedicated server - stuck

Tags: networking, server, 16.04, dns

I recently built a dedicated server with Ubuntu 16.04 and the only thing left to do is set the DNS/Nameservers on it to start hosting other domains on it.

I'm getting really confused about what to do here.

------------ What I've Done So far

I created an account with EasyDNS to use as my host DNS.  I added an A record in this account to point to my server.

I added `dns-nameservers 111.222.333.444` to the `/etc/network/interfaces` file.  I noticed my interface has this line: `iface p6p1 inet static` and not the `eth0` I see on other articles.

I added to the `/etc/resolv.conf/head` the 3 nameservers that were assigned to me through EasyDNS, after rebooting the server, these name servers showed in `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Added `server` to `/etc/hostname`

Altered the line in `etc/hosts` to `111.222.333.444 server.easydnsdomain.com server`

I even installed and ran ddclient, even though I don't think thats needed since I have a static IP.

-------------Testing my domains

I tried adding some domains to see if it would work

I changed one domain's nameservers to my EasyDNS nameservers, when this didn't work I added in the EasyDNS records an A record from my domain to my servers IP

On a seperate domain I left nameservers as default, went to advanced DNS and added an A record pointint to my easyDNS nameservers IP.  I also tried just adding an A record pointing to my server.

When I ping these domains I get `unknown host example.com` .  When I enter command `host example.com` I get `example.com not found: 5(REFUSED)`

Any thoughts on what I missing or done wrong?  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Just saw that you did add a A record. Well did you give the easyDNS enough time to update the entry sometimes it takes a while. You can test directly if you install the package `dnsutils` and then type in your terminal `nslookup your.domain.com dns1.easydns.com` for example or more specific the one that you actually made the configurations on

Comment: Thanks, that command line is new to me.  I tried it on my test domains and here are the resaults from `nslookup example.com`:

`;; Got recursion not available from 1.2.3.4, trying next server
;; Got recursion not available from 2.3.4.5, trying next server
Server:         3.4.5.6
Address:        3.4.5.6#53`

I also tried `nslookup google.com` and received the same results

Comment: Hmm?? Are you changing the IPs or are they literally 1.2.3.4, 3.4.5.6 ? Because that can't work. If you put there your own static IP it is also wrong unless you do have a DNS installed on your server.

Comment: @okcpitt Have you read any documentation so far ?

Answer (score 0):

**Please review these steps - [Source](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/StaticDnsWithDhcp)**

---

The default setup of Ubuntu does not make it easy to use static DNS servers while using DHCP.  If you use the standard ubuntu way of networking (ifupdown), you can edit /etc/network/interfaces In that file you find the entry for your interface. If your interface is eth0, then look for the following lines:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Add one line, so it looks like:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
dns-nameservers ip.address.of.nameserver
```

Run

```
sudo invoke-rc.d networking restart
```

To make the changes effective If you do not use ifupdown, you need to edit /etc/dhcp3/dhclient.conf Find the lines

```
#prepend domain-name-servers 127.0.0.1;
request subnet-mask, broadcast-address, time-offset, routers,
        domain-name, domain-name-servers, host-name,
        netbios-name-servers, netbios-scope;
```

And change them to

```
prepend domain-name-servers 1.2.3.4, 1.2.3.5;
request subnet-mask, broadcast-address, time-offset, routers,
        domain-name, host-name,
        netbios-name-servers, netbios-scope;
```

Replace 1.2.3.4 and 1.2.3.5 with the addresses of your DNS servers. Run

```
sudo invoke-rc.d networking restart
```

To make the changes effective:

---